# Generated header file not found in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

We are working on a swift project where we use a little bit of Objc. 
I have two targets and one framework with a big part of the code (also the mixed code) inside it. My two targets including this framework. (screenshot)

Now I keep getting this error.

```
'Nexx4-iOS-Swift.h' file not found
```

Nexx4-iOS is the generated header file that is been created. When I look inside derived data I will find this file. But I cannot navigate (CMD-click) to the file. So it seems that that there is some thing wrong with the linking of it?

Any help?

[image]

Comment: I am assuming you already have the answer by now, as it's been years.

Answer (score 0):

First remove is header file path from the **Build Setting** in Project in each target.
And again recreate header file.

Comment: What do you mean by recreate header file ? And which header file path?

Comment: Its seems your header file path has been changed.

Comment: You mean the bridging header file ?

Comment: Yes, Did you try in this way ?

Comment: It does not complain about the bridging file but about the generated header file. If you know what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Settings under Packaging, search for Defines Module and set it to Yes. Hope this may helpful.